# How does the scope of the data in the omptask determined?

Tags: c, multithreading, task, openmp

When is a variable first private in a task?

```
    int a;
    void foo()
    {
    int b,c;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(c){

      int d;

      #pragma omp task
     {
        int e;
        //Want to find out the scope of the variables in the task region

     }
     }
     }
```

What should be the scope for the variables a,b,c,d and e?

Comment: `a,b,c` shared, `d`  firstprivate, `e` private

Comment: I think the same but at a few places I have seen they are considering b also as "first private". So I got confused.

Comment: No, `b` is shared. You may confuse it with [this (very similar) example](https://blog.rwth-aachen.de/itc-events/files/2021/02/08-openmp-CT-tasking_model.pdf). On page 14 `private(b)` clause is used, so it is firstprivate in the task construct.